# How to interlink or add dependency between paragraphs in a Zeppelin notebook

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I have a Zeppelin notebook 'Test'. This notebook has 2 paragraphs like below

1.

```
%spark
import statements;
val df=sqlContext.read.format....cassandra..table
df.registerTempTable("users")
```

2.

```
%spark.sql
select date,count(users) from users
```

I am scheduling this notebook to run every 5 minutes. On the first run, I am getting error from the second paragraph that 'users' table is not found.

I need to add dependency to 2nd paragraph such that 2nd paragraph runs only when first one completes. How to achieve this in Zeppelin 0.6.0?

Comment: Facing the similar problem. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated

Comment: Were you able to find any solution to it? I could not find any solution to it

Answer (score 2):

Kick off paragraph 2 from paragraph 1 with z.run

z.run("*paragraphID*")

Answer (score 0):

You can run paragraphs sequentially in zeppelin 0.8

Comment: Hi @zjffdu I m working with zeppelin 0.8.0 and paragraphs didn't run sequentially I want to know if  missed some configuration

Comment: Can you share more details ? like what interpreters do you use ? Because it works for me, so it would be better to know how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thanks, @zjffdu for the quick response work with spark and MongoDB interpreter, I have to configure queries using angular and send the parameter to MongoDB to execute query then return the result in the form of table and dashboards...

Comment: Do you mind to ask the question in zeppelin user mail list and attache the note file ?